# Linux get data from each line of file

Tags: bash

I have a file with many (~2k) lines similar to:

```
117   VALID|AUTHEN    tcp:10.92.163.5:64127   uniqueID=nwCelerra
....
991   VALID|AUTHEN    tcp:10.19.16.21:58332   uniqueID=smUNIX
```

I want only the IP address (10.19.16.21 shown above) and the value of the uniqueID (smUNIX shown above)

I am able to get close with:

```
cat t.txt|cut -f2- -d':'
10.22.36.69:46474       uniqueID=smwUNIX
...
```

I am on Linux using `bash`.

Answer (score 3):

Using awk:

```
awk '{split($3,a,":"); split($4,b,"="); print a[2] " " b[2]}'
```

By default if splits on the whitespaces, with some extra code you can split the subfields

**Update:**
even easier overriding the default delimiter:

```
awk -F '[:=]' '{print $2 " "$4}'
```

Answer (score 0):

using grep and sed :

```
grep -oP "^\d+   [A-Z]+\|[A-Z]+    \w+:\K(.*)" | sed "s/   uniqueID=/ /g"
```

outputs:

```
10.92.163.5:64127 nwCelerra
10.19.16.21:58332 smUNIX
```